# angularjs ng-repeat error : Duplicates in a repeater

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I use `$http` get and ng-repeat my data to the `<li>`, the first time work but when I run the `$http` for the second time, apply to the same `<li>`, I got Duplicates in a repeater error. I know in jquery we have to use `empty()` and then `append()` the DOM, but in angularjs I have no idea how to solve this.

```
<li ng-repeat="data in data">{{data.name}}</li>

var getAPI = function(name){

$http({
        url: "http://example.me",
        method: "GET",
        params:{name:name},
        }).then(function(response){
            $scope.data = response.data;
        })
}

getAPI('john');
```

Doesn't work when I call the second time like getAPI('james');

Comment: If you don't post your code, it's difficult to help you.

Comment: Can you show the code for this please?

Comment: @R3tep here there are.

Answer (score 0):

It generally means you have an array that has items in it that have the same (or non-unique) identifiers

A really easy way to get around this is track by $index

```
 ng-repeat="item in items track by $index"
```

However, you may not always want to do this depending on your data and the scenarios you re using the repeat for.

So, for this example if your items looks like

```
 $scope.items =  ["1","1"];
```

You will get this error if you do not add track by $index, because it has nothing unique between the 2 items.

Comment: I know track by but I hestitate to use it. I wonder I get an error coz I'm ng-repeating different set of data.

Comment: @AaronMusktin track by $index just makes sure each item is unique, by just adding it's index in the array as an identifier, it's generally harmless. You should post your code and data structure if you want more in depth help, but this will fix your problem. I'm willing to bet if you look at your data coming in you have 1 or more items that look exactly the same. That's all that error really means.

Comment: I tried track by, I got a long loop error in the console. I've updated my code.

Comment: @AaronMusktin show your data structure, and what is the loop error. You might want to try ng-repeat="item in data" not " data in data"

Comment: No need, it work fine if I run it seperately, I broke when I try to run the second time after the first one done loaded.

Comment: @AaronMusktin you positive the data looks the same and you are dropping it in $scope.data in exactly the same format? May want to post the errors you are getting.

Comment: Error: [ngRepeat:dupes] Duplicates in a repeater are not allowed. Use 'track by' expression to specify unique keys. Repeater: data in data, Duplicate key: string:/, Duplicate value: /
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.13/ngRepeat/dupes?p0=data%20in%20data&p1=string%3A%2F&p2=%2F

Comment: It doesn't work for the second time even thought in my function I try to set the $scope.data = "" first.

Comment: @AaronMusktin the dupes problem is solved by `track by $index`. its very hard to tell what other problems could be without seeing how the data is structured you are trying to run the ng-repeat over. You should **not** be setting `$scope.data = ""`. You are setting it to an empty string, it should be whatever (object or array) your object is coming in. That might be your issue right there. Again - please show the data structure, it will be a lot easier to help.

Comment: My bad, it doesn't work with this data structure. https://api.myjson.com/bins/24d64

Comment: @AaronMusktin is that exactly what both of them look like?

Comment: @AaronMusktin yea those 2 should work fine. Make sure you have the track by $index on the repeat (you said you tried track by, but did you actually put track by index in and try it? you shouldnt still be having dupes issue if you did), try changing it to "item in data", and don't try to clear the repeat out by changing to an empty string, in this case the item is an object so if you want to clear the object  you do `$scope.data = {}`

Comment: I tried track by $index, can u try? this one https://api.myjson.com/bins/24d64 I get bunch of blank value.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81199/discussion-between-ajmajmajma-and-aaron-musktin).